# izimodal add navigation arrow icons to the left and right of the modal box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, izimodal

I am building a gallery of thumbnail images, when you click on an image the content will apear in a modal box. Things have gone smoothly until I wanted to add navational arrows on the outside of the modal box so that when a usuer clicks on a thumbnail and the modal pops up they will have the option to click the left arrow to go to the previous modal or the right arrow to go to the next to prevent having to close out and open each one. I am still digging but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$("#speaker_info_modal").iziModal({
                    appendTo: 'body',
                    title: '',
                    overlayClose: true,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    arrowKeys: true,
                    navigateArrows: true,
                    navigateCaption: true,
                    headerColor: '#fa582d',
                    overlayColor: 'rgba(46,0,150,0.7)',
                    padding: 40,
                    focusInput: false,
                    zindex: 10001,
                    width: 1100,
                    closeButton: true,
                    bodyOverflow: false
                });
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    //$("#featured-speakers .spkr_title").matchHeight();
                });
                $(document).on('click', '.spkr_sec', function(event) {
                    let speakersInfoId = $(this).attr('id');

                    let speakerContentHtml = $('#'+speakersInfoId).find('.spkr_cont').html();
                    let speakerInfo = '<button data-iziModal-close="close" class="icon-close">x</button>'+
                                    '<div class="row">'+
                                        '<div class="col-md-4">'+

                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="col-md-8">'+
                                            '<div class="spkr_cont">'+speakerContentHtml+'</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>';
                    $("#speaker_info_modal .iziModal-content").html(speakerInfo);
                    $("#speaker_info_modal").iziModal('open'); 
                });

                // Show default speaker region
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".speaker-container[data-region~='santaclara']").fadeIn();
                    
                      $('.btn-prev').click(function(){
    var current = $('.modal-body').find('a').attr('title');
    $('a[title="' + current + '"]').parent('div').prev('div').children('a').children('.thumbnail').trigger('click');
  });
  $('.btn-next').click(function(){
    var current = $('.modal-body').find('a').attr('title');
    $('a[title="' + current + '"]').parent('div').next('div').children('a').children('.thumbnail').trigger('click');
  });
                });

                $(document).on('click', '.switch_btn', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('.switch_btn').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');

                    let selectedRegion = $(this).data('region');

                    // show selected region's speakers
                    $(".speaker-container").hide();
                    $(".speaker-container[data-region~='"+selectedRegion+"']").fadeIn();
                });
```

```css
.fw-section#speakers-fullpage .spkr_sec p.spkr_bio, .fw-section#speakers-fullpage .spkr_sec h4 {
    display: none;
}

div#speaker_info_modal {
    max-width: 70% !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.6.1/css/iziModal.min.css



" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.6.1/js/iziModal.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="fw-section speakers-fullpage" id="speakers-fullpage">
                <div class="container">

                    

                    <div class="row pb-5">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 pt-5">
                            <h1 class="mb-1">Speakers</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7 pt-5">
                            <div class="btn-reg-wrapper text-right">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="breakout-speakers">
                        <div class="col-md-3 speaker-container" data-region="munich santaclara">
                            <div class="spkr_sec" id="spkr_modal1">
                                <div class="spkr_img_container">
                                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Square_200x200.svg/200px-Square_200x200.svg.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="spkr_cont d-md-inline-block ml-0 mt-3">
                                    <h4>Speaker 1</h4>
                                    <p class="spkr_bio">
                                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 speaker-container" data-region="munich santaclara">
                            <div class="spkr_sec" id="spkr_modal5">
                                <div class="spkr_img_container">
                                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Square_200x200.svg/200px-Square_200x200.svg.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="spkr_cont d-md-inline-block ml-0 mt-3">
                                    <h4>Speaker 2</h4>
                                    <p class="spkr_bio">
                                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 speaker-container" data-region="santaclara">
                            <div class="spkr_sec" id="spkr_modal_Shariq_Ata">
                                <div class="spkr_img_container">
                                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Square_200x200.svg/200px-Square_200x200.svg.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="spkr_cont d-md-inline-block ml-0 mt-3">
                                    <h4 class="title">Speaker 3</h4>

                                    <p class="spkr_bio">
                                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        

                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iziModal" id="speaker_info_modal">

            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you stuck with using this modal library?  The functionality you want is called a lightbox, and there are tons of libraries out there that already do exactly this.   Here's one as an example: https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/